# C++ Pass a argument through a class with array index

Tags: c++, class, parameter-passing

Is there anyway I can pass a argument through a class like below for example.

```
class cat
{
public:
    void dog(int ID, const char *value) // int ID I'd like to be the index array it was called from?
    {
        debug(ID, value);
    }
};

cat cats[18];

cats[1].dog("value second arg, first arg auto filled from index array");
```

Comment: Since you are specifying the index anyway (`cats[1]`), what is preventing you from doing so *again* in the method call? Is it rather your intent to walk something like a pointer `cat *p = cats; p->dog(...);` and have the index somehow inferred?

Comment: i don't want to do it that way I want to basically have a variable in there that will store it in the array for eg. there are 18 clients, i want to make it to where if one calls that option the variable will store there clientIndex number in the array

Comment: Why not have a member id in `cat` (filled only once at the construction) and then avoid it in all other method ?

Comment: show me how would you do it, cause i think I know what your saying but i want to make sure

Comment: @HorseFrog Ah, I see, as you have it written the contained sequence is disjoint. The `cat`s in the `cats` array are location-agnostic, and rightfully so. Without a property contained in each instance or a wrapper free function for access, it isn't likely.

Comment: here, basically I want to store an INT named ID within the class that is the passed index array

Comment: An object knows nothing about the array that contains it. (Because after all, it might not even be in an array.) If you want the value to be passed in, then you just have to pass it in yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
class cat
{
public:
    void dog(const char *value)
    {
        //debug(ID, value);
    }
};

cat cats[18];

void cat_dog(int ID, const char *value)
{
    debug(ID, value);
    cats[ID].dog(value);
}

//cats[1].dog("value second arg, first arg auto filled from index array");
cat_dog(1, "value second arg, first arg auto filled from index array");
```

Comment: so for example. a person called brad 14. he joins the game and his Client Index Number is 13 which is chosen by the server, so basically i want the function that he calls gets his client Index number and it is stored in the array. so the clients Client Index number that was given by the server is stored in the array.

Comment: I think you'd better edit your question to specify clearly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, you may alternatively use a member to store the index, and then no need to provide it in successive calls:

```
class cat
{
public:
    cat(int index) : index(index) {}

    void dog(const char *value) { debug(index, value); }

private:
    std::size_t index;
};
```

And then initialize the array:

```
std::vector<cat> cats;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 18; ++i) {
    cats.push_back(cat(i));
}
```

And then call any method:

```
cats[1].dog("text value, index 1 already stored in object");
```